# Convert null object to String

Tags: java, android, string, nullpointerexception, type-conversion

I have written an android program to load values to table-row from web service. But value comes null so I need to convert it into a string. Can someone tell me the method to do it?

```
try{                    

    SoapObject request = service.getRequest();
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = service.getEnvelope(request);
    SoapObject response = service.getResponse(envelope);
    Log.i("Service Master", response.toString());
    int count = response.getPropertyCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
        DeleteuserDetails deleteuserDetails=new DeleteuserDetails();
        deleteuserDetails.setUserId(result.getPropertyAsString(4));
        deleteuserDetails.setUserName(result.getPropertyAsString(2));
        deleteuserDetails.setUserRole(result.getPropertyAsString(3));
        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedDate(result.getPropertyAsString(1));
        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0));
        userdetail.add(deleteuserDetails);
    }
```

Now `deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0));` gets null value from webservice, so I need to convert it into  string `"null"`.

**LogCat:**

```
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject.getPropertyAsString(SoapObject.java:165)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at com.mvss.admin.Deleteuser$deteUserIdLoad.doInBackground(Deleteuser.java:81)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at com.mvss.admin.Deleteuser$deteUserIdLoad.doInBackground(Deleteuser.java:1)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-20 18:48:52.608: W/System.err(2174):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: `deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(String.valueOf(result.getPropertyAsString(0));` will transform null into "null".

Comment: This will still cause a NPE. Writing String.valueOf((Object)result.getPropertyAsString(0)) would probably work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this,

```
try {
    deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy("null");
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Instead of catching the exception or putting conditions, use
`String.valueOf(result.getPropertyAsString(0));`

It will call **toString()** method of the argument and will convert it to String and if result.getPropertyAsString(0) is null, then it will change it to **"null"**.

Answer (score 9):

Although it's not a good practice, you can concatenate the null value with "" to make it a String.

For example:

```java
String str=null;
System.out.println((str+"").length()); /// prints 4
```

Comment: It may not be good practice, and I don't know why it might not be, but it certainly is effective, simple, reliable, and doesn't seem to have any negative side effects.

Although I might advocate that the string value of null ought to be "".

Answer (score 8):

`result.getPropertyAsString(0)` alone will result in a NPE already when the property is internally null. Your stacktrace points to `SoapObject.getPropertyAsString(SoapObject.java:165)` which should be

```
public String getPropertyAsString(int index) {
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo) properties.elementAt(index);
    return propertyInfo.getValue().toString();
}
```

[source](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.java#L163)  - it will crash when `propertyInfo` or 
`propertyInfo.getValue()` is `null`.

To prevent that from happening you need to get the property not via `getPropertyAsString` but via `getProperty` and convert it manually to a `String`.

You can encapsulate that into some utility method

```
public static String getPropertyAsString(SoapObject object, int index) {
    Object prop = object.getProperty(index);
    if(prop instanceof PropertyInfo) {
        prop = ((PropertyInfo)prop).getValue();
    }
    return String.valueOf(prop); // will make it "null" if it is null
}
```

and then do

```
deleteuserDetails.setUserId(getPropertyAsString(result, getPropertyAsString(4)));
deleteuserDetails.setUserName(getPropertyAsString(result, getPropertyAsString(2)));
deleteuserDetails.setUserRole(getPropertyAsString(result, getPropertyAsString(3)));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987579/illegalstateexception-in-android-tablelayout

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0) == null ? "null": result.getPropertyAsString(0));
```

Comment: Then you are still calling .toString() on getPropertyAsString. Which you can't do, because if getPropertyAsString returns null, it is like calling null.toString().

Answer (score 3):

```
if(result.getPropertyAsString(0)==null)
{
deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy("");
}
else
{
deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check if its null then set a string for it.

```
if(result.getPropertyAsString(0) == null){
 deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy("NULL");
}else{
 deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`"Hi this will be " + null;`

Prints out "Hi this will be null" in String

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that, place the condition `if(String!=null)`.

Comment: could u please tell me elabrately

Comment: Place the condition as: if(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString()!=null){deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());}

Comment: His problem is, that getPropertyAsString == null, so calling .toString() on that will cause a NPE.

Comment: ok @NickL then change the code as: if(result.getPropertyAsString(0)!=null){deleteuserDetails.setCreatedB‌​y(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());}

Comment: @Avadhani then the NULL value still isn't converted to a "null" String. See other answers.

Comment: @NickL What i am trying to tell is check whether the value result.getPropertyAsString(0) is null or not... thats it... if null return; else convert it to string... is it not the correct way to do....?

Comment: I know, but he wants to 'convert' the NULL value to a "NULL" String, a String which contains the text "NULL". In his current code he is trying to do this with .toString(), which ofcourse will throw a NPE when called on a NULL value.

Comment: what can i do NickL and Avadhani

Comment: @user1858826 Please try to use the condition which i placed above and let me know if there are any issues....

Comment: Could do what Zapl said, it is the only answer that is different then the other 8 answers.

Comment: try {
    deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy("null");
}

Comment: ya tried the above one and if exception rises i stored it as null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987579/illegalstateexception-in-android-tablelayout

Comment: No, he caught the exception and then inserted "null". Like Gamb suggested. But @user1858826 is a bad user and probably isn't going to accept an answer anyways.

Comment: who said NickL nothing like that

Answer (score 0):

The error comes when you are trying to convert a null value to a String ( mostly it's BigDecimal)

So what you have to do is catch the exception when program tries to convert null to String and set the null value manually for the String variable.

```
try{
    deleteuserDetails.setUserId(result.getPropertyAsString(4));
}catch (Exception e){
    deleteuserDetails.setUserId(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to Piggybag ride on what @prateek said.

```
 String str=null;
    System.out.println((str+""));
```

Do it without the.length so you can actually just print out the string