# Android EditText gives nullpointer

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I got an error when I try to run my application.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction

Here is where my problem starts(Line 73):

```
USER_ID_TMP = userIdtext2.getText().toString();
```

Longer code snippet:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
    Log.i("tabs", "CurrentTab is: 1");

    DB_NAME_AND_PATH = Tab1.this.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    Log.d("Haze", "DB_NAME_AND_PATH: "+DB_NAME_AND_PATH);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewer);
    Button copyDbButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.copydbbutton);
    Button readDbButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readdbbutton);
    final EditText userIdtext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userIDtextBox);
    EditText userIdtext2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userIDtextBox);

    if(fileFound){
        Log.d("Haze", "Filefound...........");
      readDbButton.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
      Log.d("Haze", "FileNotfound...........");
      fileFound = checkFileOnCreate(DB_NAME_AND_PATH);
      readDbButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    USER_ID_TMP = userIdtext2.getText().toString();
    Log.d("Haze", "USER_ID_TMP: "+USER_ID_TMP);
    USER_ID = USER_ID_TMP.toUpperCase();

    final TextWatcher watcher= new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (userIdtext.getText().toString().equals("")) {
              userIdtext.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        userIdtext.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            }
```

Error message:

```
05-13 03:43:08.778    2079-2079/com.androidexample.tabbar D/Haze﹕ FileNotfound...........
05-13 03:43:08.800    2079-2079/com.androidexample.tabbar D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-13 03:43:08.800    2079-2079/com.androidexample.tabbar W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-13 03:43:08.828    2079-2079/com.androidexample.tabbar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.tabbar/com.androidexample.tabbar.TabBar}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.tabbar/com.androidexample.tabbar.Tab1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.tabbar/com.androidexample.tabbar.Tab1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1796)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
            at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
            at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
            at com.androidexample.tabbar.TabBar.onCreate(TabBar.java:43)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.androidexample.tabbar.Tab1.onCreate(Tab1.java:73)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1796)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
            at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
            at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
            at com.androidexample.tabbar.TabBar.onCreate(TabBar.java:43)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is that `EditText` and others in `tab1.xml`?

Comment: can you please post your activity whole code ?

Comment: May be, userIdtext2.getText() value is null. and null.toString() referenced by userIdtext2.getText().toString() returns the NPE.

Comment: `final EditText userIdtext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.**userIDtextBox**);
  EditText userIdtext2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.**userIDtextBox**);` Same Id ???

Comment: I think you have copied line `EditText userIdtext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userIDtextBox);`

Comment: @Manu I see you've been deleting the java tag from many android-tagged questions. Why? Writing in Java for the Android platform is common and IMO it's ok to have it tagged as such, with both android and java tags.

Comment: @laalto I'm removing it from questions which don't have to do much with java (oh. this questions is a java problem... sorry). In such questions the problem has only to do with android... Should I ask on meta how we should proceed?

Comment: @Manu Yes, certainly comments to other people's questions are not the right place for extensive discussions. Posted on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254642/deleting-java-tag-from-questions-tagged-androidjava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used tab1 layout to set view by using 
 setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

And  initize userIdtext2 by using id userIDtextBox from this line 
EditText userIdtext2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userIDtextBox);

Then you take value of userIdtext2 by following code

USER_ID_TMP = userIdtext2.getText().toString();

so check  if the id is **R.id.userIDtextBox is available in layout R.layout.tab1 or not** ?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your input.
Of course the name of this EditText was not "userIDtextBox" ....copy paste error....name was "edittextbox" ...stupid nameing of me:)
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Check if your **userIdtext2.getText()** is null or not. If it is not null, then use **userIdtext2.getText().toString()**

Because using toString() on null object is known to cause **NPE**

Reference : [Convert null object to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973233/convert-null-object-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is in this line

```
USER_ID = USER_ID_TMP.toUpperCase();
```

because `user_id_temp` contains nothing so when you try to convert it to upper case, since it contain nothing that's why it throws `exception`.Try it with some inital input or comment it and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `EditText` Id's (Here both are same)

```
 final EditText userIdtext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userIDtextBox1);
 EditText userIdtext2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userIDtextBox2);
```

May be other issue in line `USER_ID_TMP = userIdtext2.getText().toString();`

Here nothing found in `getText();`

So first you have to `setText("");`